# When should I HTML-escape data and when should I URL-escape data?

Tags: html, forms, escaping

When should I HTML-escape data in my code and when should I URL-escape? I am confused about which one when to use...

For example, given a  element which asks for an URL:

```
<input type="text" value="DATA" name="URL">
```

Should I HTML-Escape `DATA` here or URL-escape it here?

And what about an  element:

```
<a href="URL" title="URL">NAME</a>
```

Should `URL` be URL-escaped or HTML-escaped? What about `NAME`?

Thanks, Boda Cydo.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

URL encoding ensures that special characters such as ? and & don't cause the URL to be misinterpreted on the receiving end. In practice, this means you'll need to URL encode any dynamic query string values that have a chance of containing such characters.

HTML encoding ensures that special characters such as > and " don't cause the browser the misinterpret the markup. Therefore you need to HTML encode any values outputted into the markup that might contain such characters.

So in your example:

- DATA needs to be HTML encoded.
- Any dynamic segments of URL will need to be URL encoded, then the whole string will need to be HTML encoded.
- Name needs to be HTML encoded.

Comment: Your answer was the clearest. Understood everything without asking extra questions!

Answer (score 2):

HTML Escape when you're writing anything to a HTML document.

URL Escape when you're constructing a URL to call in-code, or for a browser to call (i.e. in the `href` tag).

In your examples you'll want to 'Attribute' escape the attributes. (I can't remember the exact function name, but it's in `HttpUtility`).

Comment: bodacydo: Sorry, I assumed you were using .NET. `HttpUtility` is a class in the `System.Web` namespace in .NET; if you mention what language someone may be able to provide a library/class that can help with the encoding.

Comment: I am using Python. I already found `cgi.escape` and `urllib.quote_plus` functions and now I am still trying to understand which ones to use. The guy below suggests to do both url-escaping and html-escaping at the same time...

Answer (score 2):

In the examples you show, it should be first URL-escaped, then HTML-escaped:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com?arg1=this%2C+that&amp;arg2=blah">
```

Comment: Why both? I don't quite understand :(

Comment: Because it's a URL inside HTML. To be a valid URL, it has to contain only characters allowed in URLs, with invalid ones escaped. However, since to the HTML, it's simply a text value, it has to be escaped for HTML too.

Comment: What would happen if I only HTML-escaped it?

Comment: Most (probably all) browsers won't mind even if it's not escaped at all. A validator will protest if it's not HTML-escaped (regardless of whether it's URL-escaped). In practice, nothing will break if you don't URL-escape it, but that's the right way to handle it.

Comment: @bodacydo - http://www.example.com?arg1=this%2C+that&amp;arg2=blah will become http://www.example.com?arg1=this%2C+that&arg2=blah when it is sent to the server, and the receiver will get arg1=this&that arg2=blah, so there are three different interpreters of the string. First the browser, then the server, then the program.

Comment: Thank you! I now understand everything!